# Important Background for Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I am a senior at a small liberal arts college, and this semester I will be taking Introduction to Differential Geometry at a big research university. I am very excited, but I have heard the course is quite difficult. The textbook is *Differential Geometry of Curves & Surfaces* by Do Carmo.

What material should I review? Which theorems from analysis, multivariate calculus, linear algebra etc. will make proofs more approachable? What are the most important proof techniques? What kind of computations should I be able to do without needing to double check a textbook?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

A differential geometry course could vary wildly, depending on who is lecturing it and what they might think is appropriate. If I were you, I would simply start working through Do Carmo. I can't think of much which could be more constructive preparation than reading the course textbook.

Having said that, I can give you advice based on what came up in the first differential geometry course which I took whilst I was an undergraduate. You should take this with a pinch of salt.

- Calculus. Brush up on basically all calculus. This includes multivariate/vector calculus, if you've done it.
- Linear algebra.
- Any geometry you've already done.

Specific theorems you might want could be existence and uniqueness of solutions to ODEs, the Fundamental theorem of Calculus, and stuff like that.